# How to reset monthly entry with dates

Tags: java, mysql, date

I'm writing a date comparing code to check if it's a new month and reset my balance to 655,000 with effect from the first of every month.The code is supposed to check if current day isn't equal to the 1st of the next month and if currentmonth isn't equal to the next month and subtract my entry from **655000** assuming its the first transaction of the month.Now immediately after that,should i decide to enter a new transaction and the cost of the first was say $100,this means i now have **654,900**,i want to store the balance after the second transaction as(**654900-(the total cost of the second transaction)**) and should follow suite for all subsequent transactions until **currentday=1** and the current month==nextmonth then the whole process would restart with the first transaction for the first day of the new month having its total cost subtracted from **655000** and all other transaction would then follow suite

in my database this the output im expecting.I'm very sorry for the not soo concise explanations earlier

```
**CustomerID||InvoiceID||BalanceDate       ||ChequeSum||CreditSum||CashSum||ReversalSum||Balance**
201743112026  10286202  2017-04-18 13:12:01  100.0       0.0         0.0       0.0       654900 (655000-100)
 201743112021  10476202 2017-04-18 13:12:09  609.0       0.0         0.0       0.0       654291 (654900-100)

private void dayCount() {
    Date theDate = new Date();
    Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    myCal.setTime(theDate);
    int currentDay = myCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int currentMonth = myCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int currentYear = myCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int nextday = currentDay + 1;
    int nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
    int tempMonth = currentMonth;

    System.out.println("Day: " + currentDay);
    System.out.println("Month: " + currentMonth);
    System.out.println("Year: " + currentYear);
    System.out.println("nextday: " + nextday);
    System.out.println("nextMonth: " + nextMonth);
    System.out.println("tempMonth: " + tempMonth);

    if (currentDay != 1 && currentMonth == tempMonth && currentMonth != nextMonth) {
        if (counts == 0) {// count returns zero if no tranction has occured so deduction starts frim 655000

            if (countz == 0) {// countz returns 0 if no cash,credit or cheque transaction has been computed yet and 1 if vice versa
                System.out.println("counts value is " + counts);
                FirstEntry();
            }
        } else if (counts == 1) {
            if (countz != 0) {
                System.out.println("counts value is " + counts);

                LatterEntry();
            }
        }
    } else {
        FirstEntry();
    }
}

/* currentRBalance returns cuurent balance in database */
private void FirstEntry() {
    transT = transType.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (transT.equals("Cash")) {
        try { // actual crud functions can be undertaken
            stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String sql;
            sql = "insert into reducingbalances (CustomerID, InvoiceID, BalanceDate, ChequeSum, CreditSum, CashSum, ReversalSum, Balance) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, code);
            ps.setString(2, cusInv.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(3, ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            ps.setString(4, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(5, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(6, ovrallT.getText());
            ps.setString(7, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(8, "" + (655000.0 - Double.parseDouble(invtotal.getText())));

            ps.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record saved successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to insert record 1 " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (transT.equals("Cheque")) {
        try { // actual crud functions can be undertaken
            stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String sql;
            sql = "insert into reducingbalances (CustomerID, InvoiceID, BalanceDate, ChequeSum, CreditSum, CashSum, ReversalSum, Balance) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, code);
            ps.setString(2, cusInv.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(3, ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            ps.setString(4, "" + ovrallT.getText());
            ps.setString(5, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(6, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(7, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(8, "" + (655000.0 - Double.parseDouble(invtotal.getText())));

            ps.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record saved successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to insert record 2 " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (transT.equals("Credit")) {
        try { // actual crud functions can be undertaken
            stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String sql;
            sql = "insert into reducingbalances (CustomerID, InvoiceID, BalanceDate, ChequeSum, CreditSum, CashSum, ReversalSum, Balance) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, code);
            ps.setString(2, cusInv.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(3, ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            ps.setString(4, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(5, "" + ovrallT.getText());
            ps.setString(6, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(7, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(8, "" + (655000.0 - Double.parseDouble(invtotal.getText())));

            ps.execute();

            countz++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record saved successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to insert record 3 " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    countz++;
}

private void LatterEntry() {
    transT = transType.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (transT.equals("Cash")) {
        try { // actual crud functions can be undertaken
            stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String sql;
            sql = "insert into reducingbalances (CustomerID, InvoiceID, BalanceDate, ChequeSum, CreditSum, CashSum, ReversalSum, Balance) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, code);
            ps.setString(2, cusInv.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(3, ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            ps.setString(4, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(5, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(6, ovrallT.getText());
            ps.setString(7, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(8, "" + (myCurrentRBalance - Double.parseDouble(invtotal.getText())));

            ps.execute();

            InvDate = ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
            System.out.println(invDate + "------");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record saved successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to insert record  4" + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (transT.equals("Credit")) {
        try { // actual crud functions can be undertaken
            stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String sql;
            sql = "insert into reducingbalances (CustomerID, InvoiceID, BalanceDate, ChequeSum, CreditSum, CashSum, ReversalSum, Balance) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, code);
            ps.setString(2, cusInv.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(3, ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            ps.setString(4, ovrallT.getText());
            ps.setString(5, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(6, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(7, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(8, "" + (myCurrentRBalance - Double.parseDouble(invtotal.getText())));

            ps.execute();

            InvDate = ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
            System.out.println(invDate + "------");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record saved successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to insert record 5 " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (transT.equals("Credit")) {
        try { // actual crud functions can be undertaken
            stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String sql;
            sql = "insert into reducingbalances (CustomerID, InvoiceID, BalanceDate, ChequeSum, CreditSum, CashSum, ReversalSum, Balance) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, code);
            ps.setString(2, cusInv.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(3, ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            ps.setString(4, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(5, ovrallT.getText());
            ps.setString(6, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(7, "" + 0.00);
            ps.setString(8, "" + (myCurrentRBalance - Double.parseDouble(invtotal.getText())));

            ps.execute();

            InvDate = ((JTextField) invDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
            System.out.println(invDate + "------");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record saved successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to insert record 6 " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you kindly fix the indentation on your code?

Comment: thanks for the correction

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you're trying to do. Could you please edit your question and add examples of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: What's your java version? Because `java.util.Date` and `Calendar` are terrible. For java <= 1.7, you could use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or [ThreeTen backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and for java >= 1.8, use java.time classes

Comment: @Hugo im using 1.8

Comment: Is that what you're trying to do?

    `for (all transactions ordered by balance date) {
        if (balance date is first day of month) {
            balance = 655000;
        } else {
            balance = balance - (cost of current transaction)
        }
    }`

Comment: The txns to be handled specially, are they all the txns on the first day of the month, or is it the first txn every month (even if it falls on the second day??)?

Comment: @Hugo.yes that what im trying to achieve..the only addition to it is that for(all transactions ordered by balance date){   if(balance date==1st day of the month   ){  then first transaction for the day to take place should automatically set new balance =655000- (cost of very first transaction)    } else if(balance date !=1st day of any month){ then get current balance from database example new balance=640000 and subtract first transaction cost for the day from it (eg 640000-2000=638000) and use new balance as(638000 as balance for other transaction deductions till new month occurs for reset)}}

Comment: @Hugo again if (balance date==1st of new month and after first transaction cost has been subtracted from 655000){ all subsequent transactions should fetch current deducted balance eg.(655000-(first transaction cost)=600000 for(all subsequent transactions after first transaction on 1st of new month){  new balance =old balance value -current transaction cost    eg. new balance =600000- current transaction cost where new balance continues to decrement with every transaction cost till new month where very first transaction cost deducts from 655000 again  } }

Comment: Well, you already have your algorithm defined, in what point are you finding problems? If you don't know how to handle dates, you can check the answer below. Also update the question with these details (it's more readable than in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not quite sure about what you want to obtain, but I think I can give you the pieces you want, and I will trust you to put them together correctly for your purpose. Since you are using Java 8, either get your date-time as a `java.time` class instance from the outset, or convert the `java.util.Date` you get. The new classes are so much nicer to work with, so since you needed a conversion anyway (you converted to `Calendar`), you may just as well convert to the better class. Here’s how to convert to `ZonedDateTime`:

```
    ZonedDateTime theDateTime = theDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Month theMonth = theDateTime.getMonth();
    boolean isFirstDayOfMonth = theDateTime.getDayOfMonth() == 1;
```

The snippet also shows how to extract the month and day-of-month from the date since these are what you need in your processing. `Month` is an enum, so you may safely compare the month of the current transaction to the month of the previous transaction using `==`.

Comment: All good except that last sentence. Using `==` with objects is a bad habit. Yes, it would technically work in this case using an Enum, but still a bad habit. I suggest you instead teach the use of `.equals` for comparison.  `m1.equals( m2 )`